# selenium webdriver SendKeys is not working for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

Same script was working fine earlier. Now,somehow, my script gets stopped after reaching on `SendKeys`.  My script is simple as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='msisdn']")).sendKeys("ABCD");
```

I am working on Google chrome browser.

Can anyone suggest me any possible solution?

Error found in console is:

> unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Comment: What has changed to before, when it worked?

Comment: A MSISDN input usually is a number. Do you try send a phone number?

Comment: whenever I see working earlier but not now, two things comes to my mind. 1) something got updated and having compatibility issues. in this case, it is chrome browser and chromedriver. I suggest upgrading chrome driver to the latest. 2. may be page got updated and not behaving like previously. in your case, i assume it is first case. so, try upgrading browser/driver

Comment: Check your chromedriver version. I had a similar problem after Chrome auto-updated. Manually updated chromedriver and everything worked

Answer (score 3):

I was able to type the password running the command twice. The first time I run the command with a empty string. The second, I run the command with the password I want to type.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='msisdn']")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='msisdn']")).sendKeys("webs");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest version of [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), and replaced it with the current driver.

[image: Newly downloaded chromedriver.exe]

For me, after the driver update, the `sendKeys` method started working correctly again.